# How to properly handle special symbols in jqgrid column name?

Tags: jqgrid

I have noticed that symbols as `€` or `°` (degree) are shown as in picture below:

[image]

This is my colName: `'Price [€]'`

How to properly handle such symbols in jqgrid?
Is there any code to use instead of symbol?

Comment: It looks like pure HTML encoding problem. You should verify that HTML file, where you use jqGrid, has `<meta charset="utf-8">`. If you use JavaScript code from separate file then you should verify that it has UTF-8 encoding too. jqGrid should correctly display the data. The option `colNames: [.., "Price [€]", ...]` should display `Price [€]` correctly.

Comment: By the way, the value from `colModel` will be interpreted as HTML fragment. Thus you can use HTML entities like `"Price [&euro;]"` or `"Degree [&deg;]"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like pure HTML encoding problem. You should verify that HTML file, where you use jqGrid, has `<meta charset="utf-8">`. If you use JavaScript code from separate file then you should verify that it has UTF-8 encoding too. jqGrid should correctly display the data. The option `colNames: [.., "Price [€]", ...]` should display `Price [€]` correctly.

By the way, the value from `colNames` will be interpreted as HTML fragment. Thus you can use HTML entities inside, for example, `colNames: [.., "Price [&euro;]", "Degree [&deg;]", ....]`.